Reprojection of crs happening inside ee.Reducers - Google Earth Engine
if my ee.Image() and ee.FeatureCollection() have different crs my understanding is that the ee.Reducer() automatically reprojects one of them to match the crs of the other one. Is that right? Does it reproject the ee.Image() or the ee.FeatureCollection()? Does it reproject one of them even if I do not specify crs: inside the ee.Reducer() (let's say, if I only specify scale:)?
Thanks for your help!
